# Show all patients grouped into weight groups. Show the total amount of patients in each weight group. Order the list by the weight group decending

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Show all of the patients grouped into weight groups.
Show the total amount of patients in each weight group.
Order the list by the weight group descending.

For example, if they weight 100 to 109 they are placed in the 100 weight group, 110-119 = 110 weight group, etc.

Comment: Consider `FLOOR(weight/10)` or something as your sort field

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 2):

So something like this?

```
SELECT FLOOR(t.weight/10) * 10 as weightGroup, count(*) as cnt
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY FLOOR(t.weight/10)
ORDER BY FLOOR(t.weight/10) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS patients_in_group,
10 * ( weight / 10 ) AS 'weight_group'
FROM patients GROUP BY weight / 10 
ORDER BY weight_group desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

I tend to try and avoid expensive floating point functions like `FLOOR()` or `CEIL()`.

A trick to FLOOR() a number to the next lower integer is to add 0.5 to it and hard-cast it to a signed integer using `CONVERT()`.

```
WITH
--- some sample data, don't use in final query ...
indata(id,lb) AS (
          SELECT  1,101
UNION ALL SELECT  2,102 
UNION ALL SELECT  3,103 
UNION ALL SELECT  4,104 
UNION ALL SELECT  5,105 
UNION ALL SELECT  6,106 
UNION ALL SELECT  7,107 
UNION ALL SELECT  8,108 
UNION ALL SELECT  9,109 
UNION ALL SELECT 10,110 
UNION ALL SELECT 11,111 
UNION ALL SELECT 12,112 
UNION ALL SELECT 13,113 
UNION ALL SELECT 14,114 
UNION ALL SELECT 15,115 
UNION ALL SELECT 16,116 
UNION ALL SELECT 17,117 
UNION ALL SELECT 18,118 
UNION ALL SELECT 19,119 
UNION ALL SELECT 20,120 
)
-- real query starts here ...
SELECT
  CONVERT ((lb  / 10 - 0.5), SIGNED)  AS grp 
, COUNT(*) AS pat_count
FROM indata
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY grp DESC;
-- out  grp | patcount 
-- out -----+----------
-- out   12 |        1
-- out   11 |       10
-- out   10 |        9
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help

```
select count (patient_id) as patient_in_group, floor (weight/10)*10 as weight_group
from patients
group by weight_group
order by weight_group desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS patients_in_group,
  FLOOR(weight / 10) * 10 AS weight_group
FROM patients
GROUP BY weight_group
ORDER BY weight_group DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
count(patient_id),
weight - weight % 10 AS weight_group
FROM patients
GROUP BY weight_group
ORDER BY weight_group DESC

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(weight, -1) AS weight_group,
       COUNT(*)
FROM patients
GROUP BY weight_group
ORDER BY weight_group DESC;
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post